# get a field value from a jenkins JSON API

Tags: json, key, jq

i have a jenkins JSON API that gives me an output stored in a variable `data`

```
{"credentials":{"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx111":{},"xxxxxxxxxxxx2222":{}},"description":"All credentials that are not bound to a specific domain.","displayName":"Global credentials","fullDisplayName":"Credentials » Global credentials","fullName":"credential-store/_","global":true,"urlName":"_"}
```

i want only the values of the credentials field xxxxxxxxxxxxxx111 and xxxxxxxxxxxx2222

the things that i have tried so far is

```
echo $data | grep "credentials"
echo $data | jq -e '.credentials[]|{}' -c
```

which does not work
can somebody please suggest something that works.

Comment: In your example, the elements inside the `credentials` object are empty objects. What are the values you're looking at? Please update your question with the expected output.

Comment: i am looking for the values xxxxxxxxxxxxxx111 and xxxxxxxxxxxx2222 here  which are the values inside {"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx111":{},"xxxxxxxxxxxx2222":{}}  the first set of curly braces

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `jq` filter:

```
jq -r '.credentials|to_entries|.[]|.key' file
```

The function `to_entries` allows to get both key and value that can then be filtered with `key` keyword.